# What are the reasons to use the id function in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, we can use the `id` function. Why are the following outputs different?

```
>>> id(123)
1824812112
>>> id(1)
1824810160
>>> id(5)
1824810224
>>> id(666)
123868896
```

Comment: The results are different because you're asking for the ids of different objects (obvious answer, at least if you made the effort to read the doc). What's your question, exactly ?

Comment: While there are a few legitimate reasons to use `id`, there aren't any for using it with a *literal* as its argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function returns

> an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

As the name suggests, this is the "identity" of the object and is meant to differentiate between objects. Still,

> Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) value.

For example, in CPython, this is the address of the object in memory.

Answer (score -1):

With every execution of the program the id values can be different. In other words do not count on the id value being the same across executions.

Answer (score -2):

Id tells the memory place of an object in memory, you can use it to see if two object share the same memory address

Comment: This is a CPython implementation detail, not otherwise guaranteed